# h2o model list dtypes for each feature

Tags: h2o

Is there a way to list the expected data type for each feature for an existing h2o model, without looking at the training data?

Similar to the output of [h2o_frame.types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548878/h2o-python-how-to-get-variable-types-gettypes-equivalent), but without looking at the training data just looking at the model object.

In this case I have a saved model file (the generic type that can be imported back into h2o, not mojo/pojo). The algorithm is gbm.

Comment: Is this for a model within a running H2O cluster or for a saved H2O model like a MOJO or POJO? Which algorithm were you hoping to get this from?

Comment: More detail added to the question above...

Comment: I had the same question -- with a function [implementing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52431210/2573061) "looking at the training data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not currently available in H2O, but I've created a jira ticket to request it as a new feature, you can follow it here https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5801

Comment: thankyou - this will be really useful when wiring up a model into a production data flow