# get predictor data types from H2OModel

Tags: r, types, h2o, r-s4

I know that I can access the predictor *names* of an `H2OModel` via the `@parameters` slot, but can I access the predictor *data types*?

I'm trying to generate an input schema for my `h2OModel`, and right now I have to cross-reference the `training_frame` and get data types from there.  Obviously, this would be a problem if my `training_frame` was no longer in memory.

Here's my current approach:

```
getInputSchema <- function(model){
  require(jsonlite)
  require(h2o)
  training_frame <- h2o.getFrame(model@parameters$training_frame)
  toJSON(
      setNames( h2o.getTypes(training_frame), 
                names(training_frame)        
               )[model@parameters$x], 
      auto_unbox = T 
      )
}
```

and an example of how it could be used:

```
#--- Example dataset ----
library(h2o)
library(data.table)
options('h2o.use.data.table'=TRUE)
library(rpart.plot) # for 'ptitanic' dataset
h2o.init()
data(ptitanic, package='rpart.plot')
survival <- as.h2o(
              setDT( ptitanic)[, `:=`( age   = as.numeric(age),
                                       sibsp = as.integer(sibsp),
                                       parch = as.integer(parch)
                                     ) ] 
            )
#--- Example model -----
fit <- 
  h2o.gbm( x = c('pclass','sex','age','sibsp','parch'),
           y = 'survived',
           training_frame = survival
          )
#--- Example use ----
getInputSchema(fit)
# {"pclass":"enum","sex":"enum","age":"real","sibsp":"int","parch":"int"}
```

I'm looking for a solution that I could apply to an existing model where the dataset referenced in `training_frame` is missing.

Comment: can you take a look and see if the jira ticket created for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543937/h2o-model-list-dtypes-for-each-feature addresses the issue you are having here as well? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h2o model list dtypes for each feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543937/h2o-model-list-dtypes-for-each-feature)

Comment: @Lauren yes thanks. it's a duplicate.  I voted to close this question, assuming the answer on the dupe target is still correct.